# Prove that $x^2+xy$ is odd if and only if x is odd and y is even.

Tags: logic, solution-verification

I have a question on proof by cases. I need to prove the statement on title.

First, I can think of proof by contrapositive :  x is even and y is odd if and only if $x^2+xy$ is even. Therefore, I let x be even integer and y be odd integer. $x^2+xy$ becomes $2(2k^2+2kl+k)$ where $k,l \in \mathbb{Z}$.
Then, I'm stuck on thinking about other one, but my guess is direct proof, which I can let x be odd integer and y be even integer. I was wondering if I have a right idea or not. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @coffeemath oh my mistake!! thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

$$x^2+xy=x(x+y)$$ will be odd $\iff x, x+y$ are both odd

Now as $x$ is odd, $x+y$ will be odd $\iff y$ is even

Comment: thank you. now i'm little bit confused because "x+y is also odd" in the first sentence. so I guess x be odd then show that $x^2+xy$ is odd therefore y is odd too?

Comment: @so0jong, even * odd = ? and even * even =?

Answer (score 0):

$$(x^2+xy)\bmod2=((x\bmod2)^2+(x\bmod2)(y\bmod2))\bmod2$$ and it suffices to try all parities.

$$(0,0)\to 0,\\(1,0)\to 1,\\(0,1)\to 0,\\(1,1)\to 0.$$

This will work for any integer polynomial.